# MPI pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose the MPI_Datatype is MPI_INT, let the *sendbuf* be the pointer of the send buffer.  If I want to send from sendbuf with an offset of 3 MPI integers, which one of the following send command is correct, or both are correct?

```
MPI_Send(sendbuf+3, count, MPI_INT, dest, 0, comm);
```

```
int typesize;
MPI_Type_size(datatype, &typesize);
MPI_Send(sendbuf+3*typesize, count, MPI_INT, dest, 0, comm);
```

More generally is there any difference in terms of pointer arithmetic between C and MPI?

Comment: If you declared `int *sendbuf;`, then the former is correct. But if you declared `void *sendbuf;`, then the latter is (almost) correct. It works here because you are using a contiguous datatype; in the general case, you want to use the extent given by `MPI_Type_get_extent()`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Many thanks for your comment!  Could you use MPI_Type_get_extent() to write up an answer and then I will accept it?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet By the way is there any non-contiguous datatype for MPI?  I am very curious!

Comment: Besides the derived datatypes you can build by yourself, `MPI_LONG_INT` falls into this category (`size=12` but `extent=16` because of padding)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Noted with thanks!  I think this information is valuable to many others.  Why don't you write up an answer to share with everybody?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I had to look up `MPI_LONG_INT`. Ah yes, not the MPI equivalent of `long int` but one of those weird min/maxloc types.

Comment: This question is really about C pointer arithmetic, not MPI.  The meaning of `sendbuf+3` is defined by C, and - as noted already - depends on the pointer type.  You can replace MPI with `memcpy` and the issue is unchanged.

Comment: @JeffHammond So you mean in MPI the pointer arithmetic is the same as in C?

Comment: @PhysicsMath the pointer arithmetic is defined by the C standard and not some specific library. Everything that's compiled with the same compiler with the same compiling options will be put under the same rule